# Using the general slicing method to find the volume of a semi-circle whose cross sections are squares.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

In finding the volume of a solid, described below, I was close in finding the equation, but neglected a coefficient. Please see the question below.

---

Use the general slicing method to find the volume of the following solid.

The solid with a semicircular base of radius 8 whose cross sections, perpendicular to the base and parallel to the diameter, are squares.

Place the semi-circle on the xy-plane so that its diameter on the x-axis and it is centered on the y-axis. Set up the intregral that gives the volume of the solid.

---

The resulting integral is:

$$
\int_{0}^{8}4(64-y^2)dy
$$

The integral I came up with is:
$$
\int_{0}^{8}(64-y^2)dy
$$

---

Where is the 4 coming from? Why do I need to multiple the equation of the circle by 4?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A picture shows that the side of the square "at" $y$ is $2\sqrt{64-y^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this has gotten bumped, here's a diagram for posterity, with a thousand words omitted.

[image: A solid with circular base and square cross-sections]

Answer (score 2):

While integrating from $ y=0 $ to $ y = 8 $ you should be  considering double the y coordinate by symmetry of y-axis.